# Error in UseMethod("mutate") when trying to add another column at end of numeric data set that sums rows

Tags: r

I get: Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric'

computing column wise sum

```
library(dplyr) 
MMIp2.nona <- data.raw1.MMIp2.num %>% replace(is.na(.), 0) #works fine
MMIp2.summed <- MMIp2.nona %>% mutate(sum_of_rows = rowSums(.)) #gives error
```

Comment: If your data is  matrix, it wouldn't work wth `mutate` as `mutate` requires either `dat.aframe/data.table/tibble` as input i.e. you can convert to `data.frame` `MMIp2.nona %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(sum_of_rows = rowSums(.))`

Comment: Greetings! Please provide a reproducible dataset. You can do so by using `dput` on your data. Details can be found here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg